# How to get the CK+ Dataset into a dataframe where one column is the image and the second column is the emotion (Is that even necessary?)

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, multiclass-classification

I want to build a model for emotion classification and tbh I am struggling with the dataset. I am using CK+ since I read it'd be on industry standard. I don't know how to format it the right way so I can start working.
The Dataset is formatted in the following way.

Anger (Folder)

- File 1
- File 2
- ...

Contempt (Folder)

- File 3
- File 4
- ...

I need the foldernames as labels for the files inside of the folder but don't really know how to get there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load all your data in a [`tf.data.Dataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) using the [`tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory) function. Assuming that your `Anger` and `Contempt` folders are located in a directory named `Parent` you can do like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory('Parent')
```

You can then access the images and labels directly from the Dataset, for example like this:

```
iterator = dataset.as_numpy_iterator()
print(iterator.next())
```